# trying to make auto follow bot for Instagram

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\VANIKO\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
sleep(5)
```

but I am getting the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary.
```

Comment: What operating system  you are trying to run this script ? Do you have latest version of google chrome and chrom driver  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `ChromeDriver` was unable to find the Chrome binary in the default location in your system.

You can use chrome options to define google chrome location like below :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path = r'C:\Users\VANIKO\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define the location of Chrome browser executable file `chrome.exe`.
Try this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\VANIKO\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
```

Just validate your `chrome.exe` is installed to default location as I mentioned. Otherwise change it to the actual path where `chrome.exe` is located on your machine.